# How does feedback factor works in equation V-/Vout

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am asking this question to understand this.

[image]

It states that V-/Vout is equal R1/(R1+R2)

Here :

[image]

V- is equal 0V. Because V+ is grounded.

So V-/Vout = R1/(R1+R2) => V- = Vout*R1/(R1+R2). But V- is equal 0V.
So why this is not working ? Because either Vout is 0V or R1/(R1+R2) is 0. But I know both of them aren't equal 0.

Source : http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/op_bandwidth1/op_bandwidth1.htm

Comment: Different question, different answear.
I'm now aiming for V-/Vout. Where V- is equal 0V.
Closed loop gain is equal Vout/Vin. Like here : https://www.electrical4u.com/negative-feedback-in-op-amp-and-closed-loop-gain-of-op/

Comment: in the previous one I asked for the equation I think.
But now i want to understand how it works for V-/Vout.
I've send the source where I've got it. I've also gave some equations I belive it is.

Comment: Read up on AN31, do some hand calculations and simulations and see it it becomes more clear: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla140d/snla140d.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation in your answer is correct! It defines the amount of feedback (beta). However - this is only one half of the truth, which means: This is only one part of the voltage which exist as V- at the inverting opamp input.

You must apply **superposition** when finding the correct value of this voltage V-
because there are two voltage sources contributing to V- :

1. Feedback part Vr=(beta)=Vout[R1/(R1+R2)], and
2. Forward part Vf=Vin[R2/(R1+R2)].

Only now you are allowed to set **V-=Vr+Vf=0** because both parts contribute to V- :

From this, we get:

**Vout[R1/(R1+R2)]=-Vin[R2/(R1+R2)]** and:

**Vout/Vin=-R2/R1.**

**Comment 1:** Because you were asking about the difference inverting/nin-inverting:

In the NON-inverting case, we have only one source (Vout) which determines the voltage at the inverting termnal (V-) because the input is connected directly to the other input termnal of the opamp.

**Comment 2**: The transfer function for a system with feedback is

**Vout/Vin**=Hf[Aol/(1+Aol*Hr)]=**Hf/[(1/Aol)+Hr]**. For Aol approaching infinite this reduces to

**Vout/Vin=Hf/Hr**.

Here Hf is a (forward) factor which contains the signal reduction in case the input signal is not connected directly at the opamp input. This is the case for the inverting configuration (**EDIT**: Hr also contains sign information when effectiv at the inverting input). Therefore: **Hf=-R2/(R1+R2)**

For a non-inverting circuit the input is normally directly conncted to the pos. input without any signal reduction - hence, Hf=1.

Therefore (non-inverting): **Vout/Vin=1/Hr=1/beta.**

Comment: @user331990 - Hi, (a) This ongoing series of comments was becoming excessive and I see you have now asked your follow-up question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630302/why-is-hf-negative-while-vf-is-positive-arent-they-the-same-but-without-vin). Therefore you must *stop* asking in comments here: (a) because new questions should not be asked in comments, and (b) to avoid duplication with your new question. || I will also move these comments to chat, to avoid future readers being put-off from the answer, by the long series of comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138345/discussion-on-answer-by-lvw-how-does-feedback-factor-works-in-equation-v-vout).

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit diagram is of an **inverting** amplifier.

However, the equation you have in your question is for a **non-inverting** amplifier and hence V- has some value other than 0 volts when a real signal is present.

For an **inverting** amplifier, \$\beta\$ is the same value i.e. R1/(R1 + R2) as explained previously: -

[What is the feedback factor in the inverting Op Amp?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630201/what-is-the-feedback-factor-in-the-inverting-op-amp)

Comment: Ok so as I understand V-/Vout is for non-inverting.
So can you also tell me what does it say this B value ? 
does it say what is the voltage on R1 ? Or what exactly ?

Comment: But on this site you also mentioned : http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/op_bandwidth1/op_bandwidth1.htm 
In the section inverting  author also mentiones that it works with V-/Vout. 
But maybe my english is pretty bad. Correct me if you can please.

Comment: The bottom line is that it hasn't really got anything to do with input voltages; it's all about how much feedback is permitted by the two resistors and, remember that feedback factor is just a man-made definition. I never use it because I find it to be pointless but, in my knowledge base, I know what it is defined as @user331990

Comment: And the thing is I need this feedback factor, to identify which feedback is stronger when I have 1 Op Amp and 2 feedbacks. 
The thing is that I read a lot about it on the internet. And I am confused because I know that V- is equal 0V. But also I know that there is that universal equation for feedback factor which was V-/Vout. But when I was calculating this V- = 0V made me go crazy. 
Like in the site you send me that this V-/Vout works for inverting and non-inverting. But also you said it works for inverting. And I don't know what is true and what not.

Comment: Feedback factor applies exclusively to negative feedback systems and mechanisms as far as I'm aware. I suggest that your solution might well be more easily solved by using a simulator. Or, going back to a link in a comment on your very first question, this tells you the answer I think you need: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112472/how-are-positive-and-negative-feedback-of-opamps-so-different-how-to-analyse-a/112482#112482

Comment: I've used simulator. 
But as I mentioned the simulator won't show me the equation V-/Vout. And how it solves it. I'm just doing it as you said in my last post with the site you used.

Comment: Use the link I just added to my comment and think about the formula I derive there. The final formula describes the situation that must be avoided or the circuit stops being a linear amplifier.