# Why is Hf negative while Vf is positive? Aren't they the same but without Vin?

Tags: operational-amplifier

For the inverting op amp, I've seen the equation Vout/Vin = Hf/Hr

Hr is the same as Vr but without Vout. Why isn't Hf the same as Vf but without Vin?

What I mean is that

Vr = Vout[R1/(R1+R2)] and Hr = [R1/(R1+R2)]
Vf = Vin[R2/(R1+R2)] but Hf = **-**[R2/(R1+R2)]

V- = Vr + Vf.

But why Hf is negative ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frryaT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why is it like that? I've seen in the comments that it is about the input network but I didn't understand it. Can someone explain it to me a little bit differently?

Here is also the link for the last post I am referring to:
[How does feedback factor works in equation V-/Vout](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630206/how-does-feedback-factor-works-in-equation-v-vout/630208?noredirect=1#comment1666564_630208)

Comment: Please define your terms. What do you mean by "Hf", "Hr", "Vf", and "Vr"?

Comment: The only thing I know is that Vf is a forward factor and Vr is a feedback factor where V- = Vf+Vr. Also Hf and Hr I don't know. I took it from the post I linked.

Comment: To include that the gain is negative (inverting amplifier). You could have Hf positive but then you have to have Aol (opamp open loop gain) negative.

Comment: I don't get it. So Vf and Hf aren't the same ? Where can I find Hf ? And why Hr and Vr are the same ?

Comment: It is the same. But notice that we are dealing here with an inverting amplifier. Thus, Aol is negative.  This "minus" only informs us that the output voltage is the 180-degree phase shift with respect to the input voltage.

Comment: Yes but as you said Vf is the same as Hf so what Aol has to do with Hf, as well as with Vf ? 
is Aol in the equation of Hf ? Also Aol as I remember is the open loop gain which was positive as I remember.

Comment: Hf is positive but Aol is negative due to inverting amplification action. And if you assume that Aol is infinity. We can't forget about the "minus" sign. So we add "-" to Hf, because this is the input.

Comment: What I meant is that where Aol in some equations apply to Hf ? Because now I understand that Hf is positive.  For example here : Vout/Vin=Hf[Aol/(1+Aol*Hr)]=Hf/[(1/Aol)+Hr]. Aol isn't negative. Also I don't know where this equation came from.